# TODATETIMEOFFSET inside a case statement

Tags: sql, datetimeoffset

I am trying to make the TODATETIMEOFFSET work inside a case statement. when I try to do this sql returns me following error. works fine if it's not inside a case statement. what am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT AP.POR,
       AP.POD Path,
       TODATETIMEOFFSET(AP.StartTime, '-06:00') as StartTime,
       MinimumPrice = (
         CASE WHEN ( CHARINDEX('','' + '''+@Provider+''' + '','', '','' + '''+@UserCompanyList+''' + '','') > 0 ) 
                THEN TODATETIMEOFFSET(AP.MinimumPrice, '-06:00')
              ELSE ( (
                CASE WHEN (getdate() < C.ClearingTime and C.OpenPriceMask = 0)
                       THEN NULL
                     WHEN (getdate() > C.ClearingTime and C.ClearedPriceMask = 0)
                       THEN NULL 
                     ELSE AP.MinimumPrice
                END
              ) )
         END
       ), 
       AP.ClearingPrice,
       AP.PriceUnits
  FROM TES_Auction C
       INNER JOIN TES_AuctionPrice AP ON AP.AuctionID = C.ID
```

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Operand type clash: decimal is incompatible with datetime2
```

also how can I make 'as' syntax work inside a case statement?

Comment: Just as a side note, you have way more parentheses than necessary. While they're sometimes helpful for readability, other times (like your double parentheses around the `ELSE` clause) they just add line noise and hurt readability. Splitting your code onto multiple lines and being thoughtful about indentation will do a lot more than extra parentheses to make complex SQL queries readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have an error on this part of your query:

```
THEN TODATETIMEOFFSET(AP.MinimumPrice, '-06:00')
```

`AP.MinimumPrice` I would expect a decimal type, and SQL can't convert a decimal to `datetime2`.

Also, to use a column alias on a case statement, you would put it at the very end just before the next comma, for example:

```
ELSE AP.MinimumPrice END))END) AS myColumnName, -- etc.
```

Comment: AP.MinimumPrice would be something like '2013-02-01 02:00:00.000 -06:00'.
TODATETIMEOFFSET(AP.StartTime, '-06:00') as StartTime, - This part works fine and it returns something like I stated above. 
Only thing I cannot figure out is why this doesn't work inside the case statement. 
thanks for the info.